# How to create a "print utility" from a Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I want to create a simple app that creates a new, system wide entry inside the "save as pdf" combobox.  A result of the app could be a "save pdf to dropbox invoices" menu entry.

[image: save pdf to dropbox invoices example]

How it works: copy paste the example flow from `/Library/PDF Services` into `~/Library/PDF Services` and edit the contents of the package ( a workflow contains several items ).

[image: The contents of the example workflow looks like this:]

For my app, I would like to have a template for this workflow in my bundle and edit, then export, the new workflow on the fly to the `~/Library/PDF Services` folder.
That way, I can enable localization of the new menu entry, amongst other advantages.

So, what's the best way to create such a "workflow" package, including info.plist, some localization, ... duplicate / edit an existing one, or is there a more magical way?
In the end, I think what I need is to create a new app on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows, including Print Plug-ins of the kind you're asking about, are ordinarily created with /Applications/Automator.app.  Are you familiar with that?

Your workflow can reference "variables". A variable based on the Text template can have an initial value. That value is stored in the .wflow file (inside the .workflow bundle) that defines the workflow. I suppose you could edit that initial value, after you've duplicated your workflow, to customize it. That seems somewhat fragile since the format of the .wflow file is not documented.

Besides Automator workflows, you can also put folders, applications, command-line tools, and AppleScript files, or aliases to any of those, in the PDF Services directories. If you would find it easier to use one of those, do so. Probably a script file would be easiest to create on the fly and customize.

For more, see [Providing PDF Workflow Options in the Print Dialog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Printing/Conceptual/PDF_Workflow/pdfwf_concepts/pdfwf_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000167-TPXREF101).

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with Automator.  I was thinking there must be a better way than duplicating some workflow.  There is little to be found out there.